# plugin "jfdatabase" already exists joomfish

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomfish

My joomla version is 1.5.24 and joomfish 2.2.3. After i install joomfish it says error: plugin "jfdatabase" already exists. i have deleted all files that include  "joomfish" and "jf". I did same with database tables. But error still there. Is there some files/tables that i didnt delete

Omeri

Comment: I assume you delete the necessary tables from the `#__plugins` table yeah?

Comment: yes i think i did. list of my plugins http://www.upload.ee/download/2670918/64699759edb88d75d19/joomla_plg.txt

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the database, open it in (for example) Notepad++, open the filter for "jf" and it it has anything to do with JoomFish, delete it, then re-upload the database.

You may also want to double check the FTP, for any references to JoomFish.

Hope this helps

Comment: well if you have search for EVERY reference to joomfish in the FTP and database file, and delete it, it can't still exist. Are you sure you actually downloaded the database to you computer and open in a text editor?

Comment: yep. strange all my permissons are writeable. I downloaded all files to my computer. in xampp it installs and everything is OK now :)